# What does <M-e> signify in VIM?

Tags: vim

I am using a vim plugin (auto-close) that uses the  command to 'fast wrap' text.  I initially thought that  stood for Atl-e but that just takes the cursor to the terminal header -- I'm running Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: I suggest you ask this over on http://vi.stackexchange.com -- the community is designed for strictly-vim questions like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Vim's documentation is extremely well-written and comprehensive.

Following `:help keycodes` or `:help <M-`:

```
<M-...>     alt-key or meta-key     *meta* *alt* *<M-*
```

So `<M-e>` is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

Comment: If Vim's documentation really *were* comprehensive, it would document what a meta-key is (rather than leaving random responders to guess it is the same as the escape-key).